# NestJS monorepo can't find processor file

Tags: nestjs, monorepo

I am using NestJS in a mono repo currently. One of the job queues is pointing to a file to leverage using a seperate process for that job. When running the build, the output is a single file in dist/apps/<app_name>. When starting the app, since there is only the one file, the code cannot find the processor file (dist/app/<app_name>/<processor_file>). Am I forced to run the build using tsc instead of webpack or is this a configurable item within NestJS?

I have looked through the doco, stack posts, and github issues and cannot seem to find anything related to this.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues#separate-processes
https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#workspaces